# changing to custom cursor in gmail with css

Tags: javascript, css, email, cursor, gmail

I'm trying to make a mail where the cursor changes to a custom cursor.  It works in my mac mailclient.  But on chrome (gmail webclient), Gmail seems to strip that piece of code.

```
cursor: url(http://www.myurl.com/mailings/client/realhand.cur), default !important;
```

help?

Answer (score 1):

Any decent mail client should at least ask before downloading resources from the web (as opposed to resources embedded in the message itself), as that's the classic way to track whether someone has opened a message (and/or do more nefarious things). (This is the familiar "Images in this message have been blocked. Click here to show the images.")

You might be able to embed the cursor using a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), but it won't show up reliably in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It's been 11 years, but here's some more info for anyone who stumbles across this question.

It turns out Gmail supports most CSS selectors, attributes, and media-queries, but `cursor` is not one of them. All unsupported CSS is stripped from the the email. You can find a list of Gmail's supported CSS in their [Google Developer docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css#supported_css).

Side note: As of 2024, most email clients do not support .cur files. You can try converting it to .png format, but the `cursor` selector has [very poor support](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/#section-positioning-display), and in the few email clients that do, many of those don't support the `url()` attribute.